# How to assign unique symbols to each data point on a graph in R?

Tags: r, graph

I have generated an `interaction.plot` using R but would like to know what code to input to assign individual `pch` symbols to each of my 8 "I" data points to better distinguish them.

Here's how my code looks at the moment:

```
interaction.plot(Background, Y, Total, xlab="Genetic Background", ylab="Mean 
Offpsring No.", type="b", pch=5)
```

Here's part of the dataset

```
Background  Y   Total
 B1         I1  53
 B1         I2  39
 B1         I3  41
 B1         I4  37
 B1         I5  50
 B1         I6  37
 B1         I7  39
 B1         I8  40
 B2         I1  45
 B2         I2  44
 B2         I3  52
 B2         I4  55
 B2         I5  37
 B2         I6  50
 B2         I7  47
 B2         I8  23
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: Added a sample of the data.

Comment: Obviously you haven't studied the instructions in the linked answer carefully.